# ODATAv4 $expand doesn't work when selecting explicit object

Tags: c#, odata, odata-v4

This first GET works perfectly fine:

```
http://localhost/webservice/odata/MyStuff?$filter=Id eq 2&$expand=History
```

It returns an array of `MyStuff` and `History` is expanded.

However, if I try to get MyStuff with the key specified, History navigation property is not expanded.

```
http://localhost/webservice/odata/MyStuff(2)?$expand=History
```

I already have the `HttpConfiguration` configured as follows at startup

```
             HttpConfiguration
            .Filter()
            .Expand()
            .Select()
            .OrderBy()
            .MaxTop(null)
            .Count();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple angles to problems like this:

1. The data itself
2. The query used to obtain the data
3. The response type of the controller method that serves the data
4. `EnableQueryAttribute` configuration

You've already demonstrated that the data exists, so we can discount *the data itself* but the remaining factors can be implemented in all sorts of combinations.

> You should update your question to show an example of your controller method that handles the *GET by Key* request

If you are using an ORM like Entity Framework then the following simple controller shows a minimal implementation that should work:

```
[OData.EnableQuery]
public virtual IHttpActionResult Get([FromODataUri] TKey key, ODataQueryOptions<MyStuff> queryOptions)
{
    return SingleResultAction(dbContext.MyStuff.Where(x => x.Id == 2));
}
```

There are of course many other ways, from a minimal standpoint, using `SingleResultAction` forces you to pass in a query and validates that it only returns a single result.

As long as an `IQueryable<>` result is returned from your method, the `EnableQueryAttribute` will try to apply the `queryOptions` to your query automatically.

If your result set is manually constructed, or is *NOT* returned as `IQueryable<>` or cannot be automatically chained then you will have to *Apply* the `$expand` query option manually.

You might do this to allow only expansion on certain navigation properties, this next example prepares an item by aggressively loading all the `History` records into memory

> Not recommended, especially if your navigation property may have many rows and the user will not be expanding very frequently, but it works:

```
[OData.EnableQuery]
public virtual MyStuff Get([FromODataUri] TKey key, ODataQueryOptions<MyStuff> queryOptions)
{
    var item = dbContext.MyStuff.Include(X => x.History).Single(x => x.Id == 2);
    return item;
}
```

This example will still allow `EnableQueryAttribute` to `$expand` and even to `$sort` and `$filter` the records in the expansion, however, because the entire available data has been loaded into memory, there is no way for the `EnableQueryAttribute` to load additional endpoints.

> in this last example, even though the `History` items were loaded into memory, the will only appear in the JSON response *if* the `$expand=History` query option is provided by the caller.

There are many other scenarios, OP didn't provide their implementation code so its a ll speculative from here. I have deliberately *NOT* demonstrated how to manually *Apply the QueryOptions* to your data query, which you can do, but until you get the hang of it, I encourage you to stay closer to a minimal implementation, we get a lot OOTB with OData, usually enough to get by.

Comment: I was missing the EnableQuery attribute - I'm awful at reading docs. Thanks for the help.